# who can access each LinkedHashMap from List Of LinkedHashMap

Tags: java, collections

I have List of LinkedHashMap how can i access each LinkedHashMap indivisibly.

```
List<LinkedHashMap<String, String>> listOfRecords
```

i want

```
List abc= new listOsRecords.1 // 1 is of first index 
List abc1= new listOsRecords.2 // 2 for 2 index
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`List#get(index)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#get%28int%29) for this. But you will get `LinkedHashMap` objects from the `get()` method and not `List`, since each element in the list is of the type `LinkedHashMap`.

```
LinkedHashMap<String, String> abc= listOsRecords.get(0); // first element
LinkedHashMap<String, String> abc1= new listOsRecords.get(1); // second element
```

You can use a loop for this if needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [List#get(int index)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#get%28int%29) method:

```
LinkedHashMap<String, String> first = listOfRecords.get(0);
LinkedHashMap<String, String> second = listOfRecords.get(1);
```